# Modify the minicart price issue on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, mini-cart, renderer

I am trying to modify the price in mini cart with a custom product attribute

now the price in the `minicart` come from:

```
myproject\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\price.html
```

and look like this

```
<div class="price-container">
  <span class="price-wrapper" data-bind="html: price"></span>
 </div>
```

So, somehow the price is binding.

Does anyone know where this price is binding? or in which part of the code 
the mini cart product attributes are render?

Comment: what do you want to do using price?

Comment: First extend checkout module , on debug mode and you will see all files rendering for price. Please post more details what changes you required in price so that community can answer you question.

Comment: i create a custom attribute for some rent product, and i want to show in minicart that attribute not the price which is 0

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to resolve the minicart price issue-

STEP.1
Create events.xml file at app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/etc/frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="custompricemodule" instance="YourNamespace\YourModule\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

STEP.2
Create CustomPrice.php file at app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/Observer

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
{

        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        $price = 600; //set your price here
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }

}
```